# Cascade Drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to create a cascading drop down list, and I am getting an error.

This contains what I am try to do with in my controller class:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(db.pjt_Statuses, "pjt_Status_ID", "StatusName");
    ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.pjt_Categories, "pjt_Category_ID", "CatName");
    return View();
}

public ActionResult SubCategory(int id)
{
    var SubCategory = from s in db.pjt_SubCategories
                      where s.CategoryID == id
                     select s;
    return Json(SubCategory.ToList());
}

// POST: /Project/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(pjt_Projects pjt_projects)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        pjt_projects.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.pjt_Projects.Add(pjt_projects);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(db.pjt_Statuses, "pjt_Status_ID", "StatusName", pjt_projects.Status);
    ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.pjt_Categories, "pjt_Category_ID", "CatName", pjt_projects.CategoryID);
    return View(pjt_projects);
}
```

**View**

This shows what I am try to do on the front end. I am getting a error with the bold line in my view code below. The error I am getting is:

> There is no ViewData item of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that has the key `pjt_SubCat_ID`.

Code:

```
<div class="span3 offset1">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category")
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)@*, null, new { @onchange = "FetchSubCategories();" })*@
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
</div>
<div class="span3 offset1">
    <label>Sub Category</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("pjt_SubCat_ID", String.Empty)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategoryID)
</div>
```

Can someone advise me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Which bold line? this one: @Html.DropDownList("pjt_SubCat_ID", String.Empty)?

Comment: O it didn't become bold, yes its that line, sorry @JTMon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the engine is trying to get the SelectList from the viewbag and it cannot find it. I am guessing that you want the Dropdown to display the items you have stored in the viewbag under "pjt_SubCat_ID" but you are not adding that item to the viewbag anywhere in the code that you have listed in your question.

If that is supposed to be the data returned from the SubCategory() method, you will not find that data in the viewbag and you should have a javascript that calls this method on the click event of the original SelectList (category id one) and binds the returned data to the subcategory one.

Comment: Okay sound. If you don't mind me asking could you help me finish of this? if you can help me, that would be great.

Comment: Just Google "Cascading DropDwonList mvc4" and you will have all the help you need :)

Comment: Would this help me [out](http://forums.asp.net/p/1900645/5394648.aspx/1?p=True&t=635042014077383439)?